# Common method in model and helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I have a common method that exists in my model because it is called by my model. Retrospectively, my view also requires this model method. In order to accomplish this, I have:

1. moved the model method to the `application_helper.rb` file
2. my model calls the application_helper method by adding `include ApplicationHelper` at the top of my ActiveRecord model

Functionality wise, it works. But is this good practice?

My Model looks like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

Comment: No, that's a really bad practice. Helpers are supposed to be **view** helpers, if you need something from a helper in your model it's possibly getting mixed with your view.

Comment: Thanks! You made me realise that I needed to call Client#my_method within my view... I've been staring at this code too long...

Comment: What dependencies does your function have?  For example does it use `request` or `params`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Writing `include ApplicationHelper` in to your model is bad practice because ApplicationHelper is a nice place to put tons of helper functions you need in your views.  These functions will end up being imported as instance methods of your model.  These functions are mostly unrelated to your model and will not work if they depend on things like `params` or `request`.  Here are two other options:

**Option 1:**

You can just define the method inside the `Client` class, and then call it from the view, like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.my_class_method
    end
    def my_instance_method
    end
end
```

And then in your view:

```
<%= Client.my_class_method %>
<%= @client.my_instance_method %>
```

**Option 2:**

Make a separate module in `lib` and include it in the places you need it.  The file name should match the module name for auto-loading to work.

In `lib/my_module.rb`:

```
module MyModule
    def my_method
    end
end
```

In your model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    include MyModule
    def other_method
      my_method
    end
end
```

Include the module in ApplicationHelper so it is available to all your views:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    include MyModule
end
```

Then in your view you can call it easily:

```
<%= my_method %>
```

Comment: Option 1 is what I ended up doing... I don't know why I tried to overcomplicate things...

Comment: @Coderama, I think Option 2 is more Rails way.

Comment: @Coderama, For me it seems like, 'my_method' is a common funcionality for both helper and model, Think of it as a independent method which will generate some out put depending on parameters received. So logically its not belongs to either AR model or helper, only they are using the function. So its better to have it in a seperate file. So if another user wants it, it can be loaded without loading the AR method. I think i have undestood u r question correctly... :D cheers

Comment: This is a neat approach - one additional step needed for Rails 5 is to force  the `lib` directory to be loaded. Add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` inside the `Application` class definition in `application.rb`

Comment: The rails way for Rails 5 is [the one pointed out by Nhat Dinh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47965263/3368420)

Answer (score 1):

If you *do* want to move it to a helper, you should move it in to the client_helper, as it is something just for your Client model and not for the whole application.

The method you speak of though, is it a static class method or an instance method? If it's an instance method, then your models (even if they're in views) can call that method. If it's a static class method, then your views can use it too by calling it like any other static class method (i.e, `Client.do_method` or something).

I don't see any reason why it needs to be in a helper, unless your method has absoloutely nothing to do with your model, in which case that would be a different question.

Comment: I can  think of a lot of code that should definitely not be in a model. Think: Code that helps determining rendering options (that could be called either in controller or view), code that checks access permissions, code that works with an intersection of multiple models that do not have a clear ownership relationship (e.g. code that works with `Swimmer` and `Runner` but not `Cycler`) etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

**5 Common method in model and helper:**

**Option 1:**

```
                    You can just define the method inside the Client class, and then call it from the view, 
                    like this:

                    class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
                        def self.my_class_method
                        end
                        def my_instance_method
                        end
                    end

                    And then in your view:

                        <%= Client.my_class_method %>
                        <%= @client.my_instance_method %>
```

**Option 2:**

```
                    module MyModule
                        def my_method
                        end
                    end

                  Include the module in ApplicationHelper so it is available to all your views:

                    module ApplicationHelper
                        include MyModule
                    end

                    Then in your view you can call it easily:

                    <%= my_method %>
```

**option 3:**

```
                    module MyModule
                        def my_method(amount)
                        end
                    end

                    In your model:

                    class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
                        include MyModule
                        def self.other_method(amount)
                          my_method(amount)
                        end
                    end     

                    Then in your view you can call it easily:

                    <%= Client.other_method(amount) %>
```

**Option 4:** 
                        Or you can declare the helper method as a class function, and use it like so:

```
                    module Myhelper
                        def self.my_village
                          "bikharniyan kallan,Rajasthan,India"
                        end
                    end 

                  Then in your view you can call it easily:

                    <%= Myhelper.my_village %>
```

**option 5:**
                      use many helper in controller
                        helper=>

```
                        module Myhelper
                            def my_info
                              "my information is"
                            end
                        end

                        module Myhelper1
                            def my_village
                              "bikharniyan kallan,Rajasthan,India"
                            end
                        end

                    ApplicationHelper=> 

                        module ApplicationHelper
                            include Myhelper
                            include Myhelper1
                        end

                    ApplicationController

                        class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
                            include ApplicationHelper
                        end 

                    YourController  

                        class YourController < ActionController::Base
                            def action
                              my_info
                              my_village
                            end
                        end
```

Comment: If  you are going to just copy a portion of my answer verbatim, it would be polite to say that it came from me.

Comment: I just combine all method form different source for user help

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, with rails 5 you can simply push your common method into `application_record.rb`

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.common_class_method
    # some awesome implement
  end

  def common_method
    # implement this
  end
end
```

Then in each model class you can call `common_class_method` by : `YourClassName.common_class_method`

or call `common_method` by: `YourClassInstance.common_method`

Comment: With this approach you would be adding `common_method` and `common_class_method` to every model in your application.  Quite often this is not what you would want, so people should choose this option with care.