# How to write methods accessible by all views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with rails 3.1.10. I want to write a couple of methods which I can call from any of the views. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887319/common-method-in-model-and-helper) question very helpful.

What I did:
1. created a module lib/unbxd_api.rb:

```
module UnbxdApi
    require 'net/http'

    def method1
    end

    def method2
    end
end
```

2. In app/helpers/application_helper.rb

   ```
   module ApplicationHelper
       include UnbxdApi
   ```

But I am getting the following error:

```
`<module:ApplicationHelper>': uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::UnbxdApi (NameError)
```

Why am I getting this error and how can i resolve it?

Comment: `require 'unbxd_api'` in your `ApplicationHelper`. If it don't work. Post your `config/application.rb`

Comment: you can create methods in application_controller.rb and declare it as a helper method and then it can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because Rails does not load lib directory anymore. You have to do that explicitly by saying:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

inside your *config/application.rb* file.

Note: If you want a helper method that's available to all views file then I would suggest you to create helper `UnbxdApiHelper` instead inside *app/helpers/unbxd_api_helper.rb*.

Answer (score 1):

Files in `lib` folder aren't autoloaded, you need to require your module

```
require 'unbxd_api'

module ApplicationHelper
  include UnbxdApi
end
```